rewiring around an outlet by splicing wires
I have a 15amp outlet that I want to rewire for 20amps (replacing the 14g wire with 12g wire) but that outlet was the first in a series that runs to another outlet across the room and to a switched ceiling light. I want to maintain that 15amp circuit, minus the first outlet, by wiring around the old outlet in a new plain junction box and also ADD a 15amp outlet further down the wall originating from the same new junction box.
My plan was to splice the 14g wire from the panel that ran TO the original 15amp outlet and the 14g wire that used to run FROM that outlet in the junction box, thus maintaining the original 15amp circuit. I also want to ADD the 14g wire to the NEW 15 amp outlet into the splice.
So I plan to splice 3 14g wires in a box. Nothing else happening in that box. One wire to the panel; one running to a switched ceiling light and another outlet across the room; and the third running to another outlet further down the first wall. Only 14g wire in the box.
The new 20amp circuit is entirely separate, all 12g wire and will power the old 15amp outlet with a new 20amp plug and a new outlet in what will become a bathroom.
I plan to use yellow wire nuts to splice the 3 14g wires in the separate box that will maintain the old 15amp circuit with 2 receptacles and switched ceiling light.
Sound like an OK plan?

As long as there is no 14 gauge wire on the 20 amp circuit.  Two circuits in one box is allowed, but not something I personally like.  You do want to mark/label the two breakers carrying power through that box.

I believe the two neutral wires must be kept to their own circuit also.  You cannot combine/connect two circuits neutrals.

Just be aware of box fill if you're adding cables to existing boxes.  It's not 100% clear (to me, at least) where all the wires and boxes are going.  Picture, 1000 words, etc...

All wiring on a 20 amp circuit has to be minimum #12 gauge wire. You will have to replace it all.
"According to the National Electrical Code (NEC), the minimum wire size for a 20 amp breaker is 12 AWG copper wire; this information is primarily found in section 240.4(D) which outlines overcurrent protection limitations for conductors, stating that a 12 gauge copper wire can be protected by a 20 amp breaker."
#14 gauge wire cannot be safely protected by a 20 breaker.

The new 20amp circuit is entirely separate, all 12g wire and will power the old 15amp outlet with a new 20amp plug and a new outlet in what will become a bathroom.

Since you are maintaining 2 separate circuits with the proper sized wiring then this would be a code compliant installation.
Good luck with your project!

Thanks Aloysius I edited my answer to accommodate their intent.
